# Did Madina muslims accused prophet Mohamed as a thief?

Tags: hadith

Was prophet Mohamed stolen red velvet cloth in badr war? Did early muslims accusing prophet Mohamed as a thief? Who is stolen red carpet cloth?

The verse "And no Prophet could (ever) be false to his trust" was revealed about a red velvet. When it was found missing on the day of Badr, some people said; Perhaps the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) has taken it. So Allah, the Exalted, sent down "And no prophet could (ever) be false to his trust" to the end of the verse.

Abu Dawud said: In the word yaghulla the letter ya has a short vowel a.

Sahih (Al-Albani)

Sunan Abi Dawud 3971

Comment: Explain what exactly you are asking? Nowhere in the quote do I see the claim that the 'Muslims' accused the prophet, rather it means the hypocrites as also present explicitly in an alternate [wording](https://shamela.ws/book/1733/13218) of the hadith. Also nowhere do I see an accusation of theft, rather the tribal leaders used to take whatever they pleased from the spoils before their distribution, and so it is possible that the people assumed that the Prophet had taken the cloth by that right.

Comment: @UmH  in the Hadith of Sunan Abu dawood, it did not mention hypocritee but a some person. That's why mostly christians use this Hadith against prophet Mohamed. From this Hadith christians claim that early muslims accusing prophet Mohamed steel red velvet. Pls give your Hadith number that mention hypocrites.

Answer (score 1):

The prophet (saw) did not steal anything - he was al ameen - the trustworthy one - and even the disbelieving Meccans trusted only him to look after their property, so why would he steal some cloth?

there has been a misinterpretation of the situation. The sahaba knew the prophet (saw) was their ameer - or leader - and therefore he could distribute the property as he wished. He would take 1/5th and distribute it amongst the poor, and the other 4/5th were distributed amongst the soldiers.

in this case, the sahaba thought the prophet (saW) - as the leader - had taken as it was his right. however, Allah revealed that could not be the case, as all the property had to be collected together first, and then the distribution happened.

in the end, it was someone else in the army who had taken it, and it was returned.

Comment: Can you give me any evidence for person return red velvet who took it.

Answer (score -2):

After the battle of khaybar, prophet muhammad pbuh said a martyr was going to hell because he stole a robe from the booty. This is from ibn kathirs commentary

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked see [answer].